# How to make rule for input number based on range?

Tags: validation, decimal, rules, laravel-5.8

I'm setting up a validator to create a custom function based on a range of value.

the user can insert on the input value.

between 0 and 9.999999, the value can have some decimal. like this 5.55
or 4.59483945.

but between 10 to 65555, the value will be the only integer.

I think I should use regex but I don't know how to do that.

thx for your help.

Comment: Can you show the code you have so far?

Comment: I'm confused here do you want float or integer type validation ?